# Console.ReadKey not returning correct value

Tags: c#

I made this code for keybind settings in my console application:

```cs
Console.Write("Awaiting input, press Esc to cancel");
ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
while (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
{
    // pressing Enter triggers this method, so we don't want the user to accidentally set a keybind to Enter
    key = Console.ReadKey();
}
if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    // set controls
}
Console.Clear();
```

But for some reason, when I press Enter, sometimes it returns the keypress before the user presses Enter. (e.g. Down Arrow)
But when you press enter again, it sometimes returns the keypress before the *first* Enter press.
Even if you press the desired value *before* you press Enter, sometimes it just returns a random key you have pressed before. (e.g. you press Z, then Enter, but then Console.ReadKey() returns UpArrow)

This is hurting my brain more and more, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Well, you're telling the user to keep pressing a different key than `Enter`. The `key` after your loop will never be `Enter`.  Replace `Console.Clear` with `Console.WriteLine("final key: " + key.Key.ToString());` and you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand these sentences:

> But for some reason, when I press Enter, sometimes it returns the keypress before the user presses Enter. (e.g. Down Arrow)
> But when you press enter again, it sometimes returns the keypress before the first Enter press.

But looking at your code, wouldn't this make more sense:

```cs
Console.Write("Awaiting input, press Esc to cancel");
ConsoleKeyInfo key;

do
{
    key = Console.ReadKey();

    if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
        // set controls
        break;
    }
} while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

Console.Clear();
```

Comment: It does make more sense, but this does not solve the problem I am having.

Comment: @NOT_A_ROBOT, ah ok, than I'm afraid I didn't really understand the question. Can you elaborate on "... when I press Enter, sometimes it returns the keypress before the user presses Enter..."?

Comment: Basically, I press a key before pressing "Enter", and the ReadKey method returns that key.

Comment: @NOT_A_ROBOT Yes, both your and my example will return the first key that isn't Enter (or Escape). So..... that's nót what you want? You want to return the first key pressed áfter the first Enter press? (Why? Because you reach this code by pressing Enter? That shouldn't be a problem in the first place)

Comment: "That shouldn't be a problem in the first place"
Exactly, because that's not what happens for some reason.

Comment: @NOT_A_ROBOT , well, you could change your while(key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) to while(key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) and do an additional ReadKey after the while-loop. That should achieve that the code only falls through after an Enter. However, I think it's a much better idea to find the source of the problem, but for that you'd have to share the code leading to this key-reading.